# Copy UIImage to clipboard on tap

Tags: uiimage, uicollectionviewcell, sender, pasteboard

I've got a UICollectionView which displays as many cells as the amount of images passed through.

I want to make it so that when you tap an image, it copies that image to the clipboard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CollectionViewCell *Cell = [collectionView
                          dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ImagesCell"
                          forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImage *image;
int row = indexPath.row;

//set image of this cell
image = [UIImage imageNamed:localImages.imageFiles[row]];
Cell.imageCell.image = image;


//enable touch
[Cell.imageCell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
Cell.imageCell.tag = row;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureRecognizer:)];
[tapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[Cell.imageCell addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

return Cell;
}


- (void)tapGestureRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

NSInteger string = (sender.view.tag);
NSLog(@"this is image %i",string);

UIImage *copiedImage = I don't know what to put here..
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImage:copiedImage];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually easier if you just implement the delegate method of UICollectionView `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and just do this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *copiedImage = cell.imageCell.image;
    [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImage:copiedImage];
}
```

Hope this helped you out!

Edit: In case you have different type of cells with images and text and you only want to enable copying under images, you will have to implement that `UITapGestureRecognizer` part and in the method called you just need to do this:

```
- (void)tapGestureRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
UIImage *copiedImage = imageView.image;
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImage:copiedImage];

}
```

Since your UITapGestureRecognizer is attached to the UIImageView, it is the sending view and you can extract the image directly from it and copy to the pasteboard.